# python flask application creating user in different directory instead of the connection it is making with ldap

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to write an application with flask to automate HRMS process for user creation in active directory. I am using my office laptop which is joined to domain.

While I am starting the debug, the code is working perfectly and making connection to LDAP which I have defined. However, when doing postman request to create user, it is not creating user in mentioned AD but to the server my laptop is joined.

Below is the code for connection with LDAP:

```py
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
import configparser
import os
#from backend.Models.user_dao import UserDao

class ActiveDirectory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.config = self.load_config()
        self.server_uri = self.config['LDAP']['SERVER']
        self.base_dn = self.config['LDAP']['BASE_DN']
        self.domain = self.config['LDAP']['DOMAIN']
        self.bind_dn = self.config['LDAP']['USERNAME']
        self.bind_password = self.config['LDAP']['PASSWORD']

    def load_config(self):
        # Get the directory of the current script
        current_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        # Construct the path to the config.ini file
        config_file = os.path.join(current_dir, 'config.ini')
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(config_file)
        return config

    def connect(self):
        try:
            server = Server(self.server_uri, get_info=ALL)
        # Create a Connection object
            conn = Connection(server, user=f"{self.bind_dn}@{self.domain}", password=self.bind_password, auto_bind=True)
            
            print(f"Successfully connected to Active Directory: {self.server_uri}", conn)
            
            return conn, self.server_uri
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to connect to Active Directory: {e}")
            return None, None
```

and below is the function to create user in `users.py` file which is located in `backend/routes/users.py`

```py
AD_conn, server_uri = active_directory.connect()

if not AD_conn:
    return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to connect to Active Directory'}), 500
        
print(f"Successfully connected to Active Directory at: {server_uri}")
      
script_path = "backend/scripts/createuser.ps1"
command = ["powershell.exe", "-File", script_path,
           "-domainController", domain_controller,
           "-username", username,
           "-email", email,
           "-department", department,
           "-emp_id", emp_id,
           "-display_name", display_name,
           "-first_name", first_name,
           "-last_name", last_name,
           "-line_manager", line_manager,
           "-phone_number", phone_number,
           "-designation", designation]

       
with open(log_file, "a") as log:
    result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=log, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)

    if result.returncode == 0:
        return jsonify({'message': 'User onboarded successfully and created in Active Directory'}), 200
    else:
        error_message = result.stderr.strip()
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to create user in Active Directory. See log for details.'}), 500
```

Need assistance on this